# Must start with "M", how you justify it?

Tags: combinatorics

**Question:**

How many different letter arrangement can be made from the letters of *"Mathematics"* that must start with "M"?

Answer is $907200$.

My understanding is:

- Total $11$ alphabets
- Total $2$ similar alphabets (M's)

Therefore it should be $\frac {11!}{2!}$ but its not correct.

Comment: look again at how many repeated letters (similar alphabets) there are.

Answer (score 4):

There are 11 letters in the word MATHEMATICS.

The arrangement must start with the letter $M$.  So there are 10 letters we can play around with.  This is $10!$ arrangements.  But note that there are two $T$s in these 10 letters.  This reduces the arrangements to $10!/2 = 1814400$.

Finally, there are also two $A$s in the remaining 10 letters.  Therefore we have $1814400 / 2 = 907200$ total arrangements.